Flutter Shaders error: 'exp' : no matching overloaded function found
I am attempting to learn shaders in Flutter by following the examples in The Book of Shaders but I am getting the following error:

'exp' : no matching overloaded function found

Here is my shader:
#include <flutter/runtime_effect.glsl>

// Uniform variables passed from the application
uniform vec2 uResolution; // The resolution of the screen (width, height)
uniform float uTime;      // The elapsed time in seconds
uniform vec2 uMouse;      // The mouse position (x, y)

// Output color of the fragment
out vec4 fragColor;

// Function to plot a line on the Y-axis using a value between 0.0 and 1.0
float plot(vec2 normalizedCoords, float lineYPosition) {    
    // Create a smooth transition around the lineYPosition
    return smoothstep(lineYPosition - 0.02, lineYPosition, normalizedCoords.y) 
         - smoothstep(lineYPosition, lineYPosition + 0.02, normalizedCoords.y);
}

void main() {
    // Normalize the fragment coordinates to the range [0.0, 1.0]
    vec2 normalizedCoords = FlutterFragCoord().xy / uResolution;

    // Calculate the y position using a power function to create a curve
    float y = exp(normalizedCoords.x, 5);

    // Initialize the color vector with the calculated y value
    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    // Plot a line at the calculated y position
    float lineYPosition = plot(normalizedCoords, y);
    
    // Blend the line color (green) with the base color
    color = (1.0 - lineYPosition) * color + lineYPosition * vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // Output the final color with premultiplied alpha
    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}


The issue is that the exp() takes a single argument so you can't just replace it in the shader as the text suggests. Updated shader below works:
#include <flutter/runtime_effect.glsl>

// Uniform variables passed from the application
uniform vec2 uResolution; // The resolution of the screen (width, height)
uniform float uTime;      // The elapsed time in seconds
uniform vec2 uMouse;      // The mouse position (x, y)

// Output color of the fragment
out vec4 fragColor;

// Function to plot a line on the Y-axis using a value between 0.0 and 1.0
float plot(vec2 normalizedCoords, float lineYPosition) {    
    // Create a smooth transition around the lineYPosition
    return smoothstep(lineYPosition - 0.02, lineYPosition, normalizedCoords.y) 
         - smoothstep(lineYPosition, lineYPosition + 0.02, normalizedCoords.y);
}

void main() {
    // Normalize the fragment coordinates to the range [0.0, 1.0]
    vec2 normalizedCoords = FlutterFragCoord().xy / uResolution;

    // Calculate the y position using a power function to create a curve
    float y = exp(normalizedCoords.x * .5) * 0.5;

    // Initialize the color vector with the calculated y value
    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    // Plot a line at the calculated y position
    float lineYPosition = plot(normalizedCoords, y);
    
    // Blend the line color (green) with the base color
    color = (1.0 - lineYPosition) * color + lineYPosition * vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // Output the final color with premultiplied alpha
    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}

